# How can i add function to this script

Tags: php, dropdown, form-submit

i found this script online and i want to add a submit button that sends you on selected city. Sorry for the stupid question, i'm a newbie.

Exemple:

Dropdown selection: Belgium->West Flanderi->Brugge

The page redirects you to:

https://www.yoursitename.com/city/belgium/west-flanderi/brugge

Here is the [link](http://www.lisenme.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/) with the demo

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#country').on('change',function(){
    var countryID = $(this).val();
    if(countryID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'country_id='+countryID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#state').html(html);
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
    }
});

$('#state').on('change',function(){
    var stateID = $(this).val();
    if(stateID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'state_id='+stateID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#city').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
    }
});
  });
  </script>


<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

//Get all country data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY country_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<select name="country" id="country" >
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['country_id'].'">'.$row['country_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>

<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="">Select country first</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Select state first</option>
</select>
```

**ajaxData.php**

```
    <?php
    //Include database configuration file
    include('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST["country_id"]) && !empty($_POST["country_id"])){
//Get all state data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id =         ".$_POST['country_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY state_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

//Display states list
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select state</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option     value="'.$row['state_id'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["state_id"]) && !empty($_POST["state_id"])){
//Get all city data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id =     ".$_POST['state_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY city_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

//Display cities list
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select city</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option     value="'.$row['city_id'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">City not available</option>';
}
}
?>
```

**dbConfig.php**

```
    <?php
    //db details
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'lisenme';

    //Connect and select the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's the question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

What you basically have to do, is add another event bound to change of 'city' selection box as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#city').on('change',function()
  {
      var cityId = $(this).val();

      window.location.href = $('#country').val() + "/" + $('#state').val() + "/" + $(this).val();
  });
});
```

Here's the full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4sy9nfg7/1/

Comment: @user3570817 If it helped you, mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot... One more thing, with your solution after selecting a city my link is like this: https://www.yoursitename.com/19/306/1808 
ajaxData.php is extracting data for db based on contry_id state_id city_id. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3570817 Yes, you have to change `value` of selects' options to `country_name` etc. instead of `country_id`.

Comment: it is possible to add extension .html or .php  with your code and remove %20 from url?

Comment: @user3570817 %20 is a whitespace.
If you want to replace spaces with "-", you need to do it on the options.